Company Directors Disqualification Act 1986 disqualification reasons - UK
After searching the Companies House for a certain director that has been disqualified the reason for disqualification is:
"Reason
Company Directors Disqualification Act 1986 (Section 7): Disqualification order or undertaking; and reporting provisions"
What does that mean in plain English? Does it provide any actual information about why they have been disqualified or is it just a generic - high level description of the disqualification?

Section 7 of the Companies Directors Disqualification Act basically disqualifies directors of companies that become insolvent, with some additional details on when this happens, and how long the disqualification lasts.
